# Making ‘return’ in child method affect the rest of the scope in its parent method

Tags: swift, methods, return

### Can a 'return' statement embedded in a child method affect the rest of the scope of its parent method?

*(I'm a beginner in swift)*

**Context/What I want to achieve:** betaChild() is within alphaParent(). I want the 'return' in betaChild() to stop the execution of the print("message C") in alphaParent() when betaChild's 'color' parameter is true

**My code:**

```
    func betaChild (color: Bool) {
        if color {
            print("message A")
            return
        }
        print ("message B")
    }

    func alphaParent () {
        betaChild(color: false)
        print("message C")
    }

    alphaParent()
```

**Case 1: color parameter in betaChild is 'false'**

This prints both "message B" and "message C", which is OK.

**Case 2: color parameter in betaChild is 'true'**

This prints both "message A" and "message C". (**Getting back to the question**: Is there a way to just print "message A"? and stop the execution of the rest of alphaParent?)

---

**What have I done so far?:**

Already tested in the playground. Because of the print results, I assume 'return' can only affect the scope of betaChild

---

Suggestions to achieve what I want (if possible) in other ways are welcome

Thank you :)

***Bonus track question:*** Is there a difference if I write the code for alphaParent before betaChild? (I know the computer reads line by line, so if I call betaChild() before writting it, shouldn't it be inaccesible? I tried both ways in the playground and it worked)

Comment: One way is the change the beta function to return a `Bool` and in the alpha function, evaluate the return value of beta with an if statements to see if further execution is allowed.

Comment: It's difficult to give you your best solution because we just don't know enough. For example, you could create `var colorIsTrue = false` in the scope of these two methods, set it in the child and pass the parent through a `guard` but that may not work in your actual use case because we don't know what else is in the parent (or the child) and if `guard` really is appropriate. But it seems that using flags (`Bool` indicators that mark when and when not to execute) is probably the best way forward knowing what we know.

Comment: Thank you Miket25 and iabuseservers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a return value to `betaChild()` like so:

```
func betaChild (color: Bool) -> Bool {
    if color {
        print("message A")
        return true
    }
    print ("message B")
    return false
}

func alphaParent () {
    if !betaChild(color: false) {
        print("message C")
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work fine and a perfectly acceptable solution.  Depending on what is required (it was stated to stop the rest of the execution) a guard statement might be better than an if statement in the alphaParent.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help :)

Comment: @Ryoko, and also, no, it doesn't matter if you write one function before another.